# how to rename file using camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have a question related to camel context programming.

I am using the download route, downloaded a file as test.cot 
I need to put this file into another route, and convert test.cot to test.xml.

Does anyone know how to write it in spring xml in camel context ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [File2 component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) ?

There are some great examples on how to configure this.

For the example you gave this could be the second route (called with [direct](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html)):

```
<route>
  <from uri="direct:report"/>
  [...]
  <to uri="file:target/reports/?fileName=test.xml"/>
</route>
```

Replace the [...] by some **[transformation](http://camel.apache.org/message-translator.html) from .col to .xml** format if needed.